# MouseListener in Java graphic

Tags: java, swing

I'm using Mouselistener to make my head's eyes open when MouseInside is true, and to close when MouseInside is false. (aka when the mouse is hovering over the head the eyes are open and when it's not they're closed). I started off by creating the class Head which extends JPanel, and creating the private boolean mouseInside. I then created the dimension, added a border and then created the nested class MyMouseListener which initialized the boolean as true or false depending on the position of the mouse, then calling repaint. I then added the mouselistener to my Head Object. Below this I constructed my Head object, and the eye objects depending on whether the mouseInside boolean was true or false. Below that I created my JFrame to demonstrate and construct the Head.

I'm not sure why it's not not working, here's my code (I'm a new programmer)..

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.geom.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Head extends JPanel

{

private boolean mouseInside;

public Head(boolean mouseInside)

{

this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));

class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

final boolean mouseInside = true;

repaint();

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

final boolean mouseInside = false;

repaint();

}

}

this.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());

}

@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

super.paintComponent(g);

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

//face

g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));

g2.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);

g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 200, 120, 140));

//eyes.. open in mouseinside is true and closed if not

if (mouseInside == true) {

g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);

g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(90, 250, 20, 20));

g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);

g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(40, 250, 20, 20));

}

else if (mouseInside == false) {

g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(90, 250, 20, 5));

g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(40, 250, 20, 5));

}

//nose

g2.setPaint(Color.ORANGE);

g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(65, 270, 20, 20));

//mouth

g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.0f));

g2.setPaint(Color.RED);

g2.fill(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(50,300,50,15,15,10));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame f = new JFrame("Head demo");

f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

f.add(new Head(true));

f.add(new Head(false));

f.add(new Head(false));

f.pack();

f.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Don't remove the text from your question. If the question has been solved then don't forget to "accept" the answer that helped solve the problem by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `mouseInside` parameter that you pass to the `Head` class constructor or change its name. 
Your class variable  `mouseInside` is shadowed with that parameter.

Comment: @Careleus1 it will be nice if you marked this as the solution

Comment: And there's no need to remove the question contatining if it has been solved. It can be useful for somebody later

Answer (score 1):

It's **very** difficult to read your code as format. However, you seem to have a variable of the same name in different scopes.

```
final boolean mouseInside = false;
```

Isn't going to do anything. Remove the `final boolean`. (The old restriction on accessing `final`s of enclosing context only referred to parameters and locals of methods and constructors, not fields of objects and classes.)